# Create new column based on a value of another column in a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A snippet of my current data-frame is:

```
     |commentID | commentType |depth | parentID   |                                    
     |:-------- |:-------------------------------:| 
0    |58b61d1d  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        |
1    |58b6393b  | userReply   | 2.0  | 58b61d1d.0 |     
2    |58b6556e  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        |
3    |58b657fa  | userReply   | 3.0  | 58b61d1d.0 |
4    |58b657fa  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        |
```

I want the data-frame to look like:

```
     |commentID | commentType |depth | parentID   | receiveAReply |                                  
     |:-------- |:--------------------------------|--------------:| 
0    |58b61d1d  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        | 1             |
1    |58b6393b  | userReply   | 2.0  | 58b61d1d.0 | 0             |
2    |58b6556e  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        | 0             |
3    |58b657fa  | userReply   | 3.0  | 58b61d1d.0 | 0             |
4    |58b657fa  | comment     | 1.0  | 0.0        | 0             |
```

- An added column: receiveAReply
- Where if any comment receives a reply it is assigned 1. Even if a comment has multiple replies, it is still only assigned 1 or 0.
- all user replies receive 0 even if that reply has a reply, e.g depth = 3.0. Such that I only care about comments on the actual article and if they received a reply, not the number of replies or the replies to these replies.
- Therefore, I am focusing on user replies with depth 2.0 and what commentID's do their parentID's match.

I have the following code, however it is assigning the whole receiveAReply column Nan, where I try create another column 'replies' where they it has the parent ID's of depth 2.0. I tried to to assign 1 based on if any commentID's match these parent ID's:

```
df['replies'] = df.loc[df.depth == 2.0, ['parentID']]
df['receiveAReply'] = df.loc[df.commentID == df.replies, [1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC your conditions, you just miss to extract the left part of `parentID` column:

```
pid = df.loc[df['depth'] == 2, 'parentID'].str.split('.').str[0].values

df['receiveAReply'] = 0
df.loc[df['commentID'].isin(pid), 'receiveAReply'] = 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  commentID commentType  depth    parentID  receiveAReply
0  58b61d1d     comment    1.0         0.0              1
1  58b6393b   userReply    2.0  58b61d1d.0              0
2  58b6556e     comment    1.0         0.0              0
3  58b657fa   userReply    3.0  58b61d1d.0              0
4  58b657fa     comment    1.0         0.0              0
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: yes thanks @Corralien, I came to my own solution as-well. Posted it above.

Comment: You should use a vectorized version if you have many records in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
df['replies'] = df.loc[df.depth == 2.0, ['parentID']]

def test(x, y):
    if x in y.values:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


df['getsReply'] = df['commentID'].apply(lambda x: test(x, df['replies']))
```